# How to customize nuxt build so that to upload changes only?

Tags: build, nuxt.js

I have a nuxtjs project, and let's suppose I built it and deployed it to my host in the web.
I'm keeping making changes and updates to it. Each time I finish from updating some components/styles I have to run build command. My problem is this will re-generate the entire nuxt project which I have to upload and replace all the old files (clients visiting the website also have to load it as first load, no cache).
Is there a way so that I can only upload the changed pages/components or whatever files ?

I tried splitChunks to get them separately, also making filenames with hash based on content (to identify new files` names which are different and should not loaded from cache). But even unchanged parts seems to have different hash and file names.

Is there a proper way to achieve this idea ?